# confusing if condition in modal.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys i was just going through the code inside modal.js , it s jquery plugin .

you can check it out [here , line 284 .](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/modal.js#L284)

can somebody explain what the below line is really doing ? 
espically this part :

```
  data[option](_relatedTarget)
```

is the above line calling a function or passing a parameter , what exactly is it doing ??

if i `console.log(data[option])` , i get `Modal.prototype.hide()` on document load and 
  `function Modal.prototype.toggle()` when i click on the launch button .

if i console.log _relatedTarget i get undefined on document load and

```
 <button data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
```

when clicking on launch button.

put together though , what exactly is this line doing ?

```
data[option](_relatedTarget).
```

Heres a demo of the plugin in action : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/599ok4nn/).

Its critical for me to understand what that perticular line is doing for certain. would appreciate any explanation , if i am not clear about anything , please tell me so in the comments , i'll try being clearer .

Thanks .

Alexander.

Comment: @JitendraPancholi I do not understand why he can't do that.. If you see the flag section, you will not find a reason why this question should be closed. What he asked is clear enough and he is not seeking for recommendation either. I find this question perfectly viable.

Comment: @noc2spamツ Great, then please do the honor :)

Comment: @JitendraPancholi i asked to expalin a line , not a library ! .

Comment: Same thing, for that we have to first understand it by own ;-)

Comment: My question implies not to tell me necessarily what exactly what this line is doing , but to explain , and rather take and educated guess at what that line is doing in the plugin . btw, its a plugin , not a library . are u sure you know what your talking about ?

Comment: Not sure about any if condition, but data appears to hold an array of functions, `option` picks a specific function out of that array, and it is called with `_relatedTarget` as a variable.

Comment: @EvanKnowles , Thats good enough to get me started . :) Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data[option]` is using variable indexer on `data` to get its `option` property.

The value of of this property may change, as you've seen, but in both cases, it represents a method, either `hide()` or `toggle()`.

`_relatedTarget` is a parameter to the method, presumably designating which element should be hidden or toggled.